# How to prevent form input to reload a page when receiving `Enter` key

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 form as follows, which is styled with Bootstrap3 and contains a `range` input and a `number` input. The two inputs are linked so that whenever I change the `range` value, the `number` input is updated and vice versa.

What's bothering me is that when I change the `number` input value and hit the `Enter` key, the whole web page reloads and this wipes out all other data loaded into the page with JavaScript.

My questions is, how can I change the HTML/code to disable this reloading behavior?

Thanks.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="range" class="policy_slider" name="demandRange" min="0.1" max="10" value="1" oninput="this.form.demandInput.value=this.value"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <input type="number" name="demandInput" min="0.1" max="10" value="1" step="any" oninput="this.form.demandRange.value=this.value"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped. I went with the `return false` solution as it is short. But others may well work too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the form submit to use javascript and "return false".   Afterwards, you can use another function to do the actual submit.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="return false;">
```

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/m3veL3uh/

Comment: use preventDefault() instead of return false

Answer (score 3):

As there are already plain old JS solutions, my answer is based on JQuery. Also, Bootstrap JS requires Jquery. So try this:

```
$("form").keypress(function(e) {
  //Enter key
  if (e.which == 13) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

If you have multiple forms in your page use this :

```
 $("#form_id").keypress(function(e) {
      //Enter key
      if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

where `form_id` is the id specified to your form something like this: `<form id="form_id">...</form>`

Courtesy: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-disable-enter-key-on-forms

Comment: should use preventDefault() instead of return false

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky using preventDefault() does nothing for me, where as return false at least stops the from submitting at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Ajax to submit the form asynchronous - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
Otherwise to stop the form submit is pretty straight forward:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP wants the form to submit *at all*.

Comment: noted, then this should be dealt with preventDefault() as it is the cleanest way

Comment: why the downvote? isn't e.preventDefault() going to stop the submission of the form "at all"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folowing code to prevent the enter key from submitting the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

</script>
```

I found it at http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php The link shows how to do it when the input field is a text field. I removed that part and it will prevent it on all fields.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to avoid submitting form.

`<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit='return false'>`

If form submit is not required, try to remove form and use Ajax if required.